# if x = any object in list[ ] Python

Tags: python

How do we do it in python if I want to find if x is equal to any object inside a list?

something like

```
if x == list[any]:
    do something
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpler:

```
In [1]: lst = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: 3 in lst
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 4 in lst
Out[3]: False
```